# Internal product on intersection (co)homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, intersection-cohomology

My question is short. Under what circumstances, if any, does there exist a well-defined internal product on the intersection cohomology groups of a pseudomanifold? I'm curious to know whether there is any natural algebraic structure that arises from such a product on these groups.

Answer (score 2):

With torsion free conditions on the space, there is an internal cup product on the top perversity intersection cohomology. More generally you can have an internal cup product for perversities that are higher than top. See Chapter 7 of the preprint of my book (which is currently still available on my website). However, you should note that this pairing won't in general be nonsingular.